# How to vertically center a div with sass (compass)?

Tags: css, sass, vertical-alignment, mixins, compass-sass

Well, everything is in the question...
I'm working on a login form that I would like to align vertically at the center of the body.
I'm new to sass and compass, and I struggle to use the right mixin for this...

The html code is pretty simple:

```
<body>
   <div>
       A div of unknown height to be vertically centered.
   </div>
</body>
```

This is the CSS3 code that would make it work:

```
 <style>
    html{
      height:100%;
    }
    body{
      height:100%;
      display:flex; 
      align-items:center;
      /* I spared all the compatibility properties for the different browsers */
    }
</style>
```

___EDIT :

I came up to something like this, but I realized I misunderstood the way to use the parent selector with SASS:

```
div.ieVerticalCentered {
    body.verticalCentering & {
        height:100%;    
        display:-ms-flexbox;
        display:-moz-box;
        display:-webkit-box;
        display:-webkit-flex;
        display:flex;       
        -ms-align-items:center;
        -moz-align-items:center;
        -webkit-align-items:center;
        align-items:center;
            html.verticalCentering & {
            height:100%;
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore, the core question is: is it possible to apply a specific style to a parent element when a child element has a specific class.

In my knowledge, it's not possible with static CSS, but could be done with JS. Having just discovered Sass, I was wondering if something nice could be considered...

Comment: please, share your markup or provide at least a short valid example in a fiddle. The login form have fixed width/height or not? What browser and version you need to support?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Comment: Not every CSS trick has a mixin written for it in Compass.  If you don't know what CSS you need to get the job done, how can you possibly ask Sass or Compass to do it?

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of the provided thread ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use this mixin to centre content.  It uses tranforms so not all versions of IE are supported.

MIXIN:

```
@mixin centre($axis: "both"){
    position:absolute;
    @if $axis == "y"{
        top:50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    @if $axis == "x"{
        left:50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    @if $axis == "both"{
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }   
}
```

USAGE:

```
Y axis : @include centre(y);
X axis : @include centre(x);
Both axis : @include centre;
```

WORKING EXAMPLE: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2LXD/)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is much nicer than my solution!

Comment: It seems to be more useful to set `position:relative` otherwise your element is going to jump to either the top or left (depending on whether X or Y axis is selected) of whatever parent element has its own position set to either absolute or relative

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution.

A specific class should be added to the `html`tag.

```
html.verticalCenter { // Center vertically body's block-children
    height: 100%;
    & body {
        height:100%;    
        display:-ms-flexbox;
        display:-moz-box;
        display:-webkit-box;
        display:-webkit-flex;
        display:flex;       
        -ms-align-items:center;
        -moz-align-items:center;
        -webkit-align-items:center;
        align-items:center;
    }
}
```

Or, if you've got compass :

```
html.verticalCenter { // Center vertically body's block-children
    height: 100%;
    & body {
        height:100%;    
        @include display-box;           
        @include box-align(center);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vertical-align {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Link:

https://github.com/DimitriMikadze/sass-useful-mixins

Comment: This adds nothing over the existing answers (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23267046/1652962).